# "No match" error after introducing std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++17, enable-if

I have an operator (in this case `operator&=`, but that is not an issue) that works fine, until i introduce `std::enable_if_t` into the mix.

It is simpler to explain with the code example:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_unsigned_v<T>>>
MyClass& MyClass::operator&=(T d)
{ /*... */ }

// then in main
MyClass a;
a &= static_cast<unsigned char>42;
a &= (unsigned long long)47;
```

If i comment out the `std::enable_if_t` block, then it compiles and runs as expected, but once i place it in there it produces errors in the format

```
test.cpp:42:7: error: no match for ‘operator&=’ (operand types are ‘MyClass’ and ‘unsigned char’)
  a &= static_cast<unsigned char>(42);
  ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from test.cpp:4:0:
file.hpp:69:103: note: candidate: template<class T, typename std::enable_if<(is_integral_v<T> && is_unsigned_v<T>), void>::type <anonymous> > MyClass& MyClass::operator&=(T)
  template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_unsigned_v<T>>> MyClass& operator&=(T d);
                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~
file.hpp:69:103: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:42:39: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
  a &= static_cast<unsigned char>(42);
```

I feel like i am missing something simple here. I have even already tried hinting the compiler by calling `a.operator&=<unsigned char>(static_cast<unsigned char>(42))` to see if it will work, but it doesn't.

Comment: `template<void> void someFunc(){}` is not valid syntax. `typename` or `class` is missing at the second template parameter:   `template<typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<>...`

Comment: @rafix07, Thanks, i have added `typename = ` before `std::enable_if_t` and it worked immediately. If you write it up as an answer, i will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `class`/`typename` at the second template parameter in definition of

```
template<typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_unsigned_v<T>>>
                     ^^^^^
MyClass& MyClass::operator&=(T d)
```

When the condition `std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_unsigned_v<T>` is true, `enable_if::type` is `void`. Without `class` `void` is treated as non-type template parameter what is wrong (`void` cannot be used as non-type parameter [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)).

By using `class`/`typename` the second parametr is defined as type parameter which takes void -  `class SomeTypeName = void` if the condition in enable_if is true, or this function template is discarded from overloads set when enable_if's condition is false.